# How to host multiple sites from virtual box Ubuntu lamp stack

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, apache-http-server

I'm pretty close to doing what I want, but alas, the solution to the final hurdle eludes me. Essentially I'm trying to get to a position where I can host multiple sites on one vb and access them using a simple url from either machine...

**My setup:**

Windows 7 host which contains an entry in hosts file which reads: `192.168.0.30 laravel.dev`
I have a DHCP reservation for this address, which reserves it for my virtualbox's unique mac address

Virtualbox is set up with a bridged network adapter and promiscuous mode: allow all (not sure if this is necessary)
I have made no changes to the hosts file on guest os.

I have created a new file named laravel.dev at `/etc/apache2/sites-available` called `laravel.dev` and edited it as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName *.laravel.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel.dev/public/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/laravel.dev/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/laravel_error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/laravel_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have then enabled it (I thought) by typing `sudo a2ensite laravel.dev` and restarting apache

**Current Situation:**

So at the moment I can access by web root (`/var/www/`) from the host by typing `http://laravel.dev/` in my address bar and I can access it from my guests browser by typing `localhost`

I can access my projects index file (`/var/www/laravel.dev/public/index.php`) from the host by typing `http://laravel.dev/laravel.dev/public` in my address bar and I can access it from my guests browser by typing `localhost/laravel.dev/public`

**What I want**

This is OK but what I would like is to be able to access the root of my site (`/var/www/laravel.dev/public/index.php`) by simply typing laravel.dev in the address bar of either machine - Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here. I would be eternally grateful.

**Additional info requested:**

result of ls -l in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Feb 26 17:16 000-default -> ../sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Feb 26 18:27 laravel.dev -> ../sites-available/laravel.dev
```

...happy to provide any other info which may help solve this.

Also, other than install the lamp stack. I really haven't done anything other than what is listed here - if I haven't mentioned I probably haven't done it so ANY suggestions are appreciated. Safe to assume your dealing with a linux noob... no offense will be taken.

Comment: Are you also hosting your own DNS?

Comment: no I'm not. should I be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the problem is a DNS problem, although I do question if the file you have made is actually being read by Apache - the line "DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel.dev/public/" should be enough to get that working.

[ Indeed if this is all you are trying to do, do you need the other guff you have put in ?   If not, I'd try removing this file and modifying the DocumentRoot in the main apache config ].

If this does not solve your problem, can you provide the result of "ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled" as there should be a symlink in there to sites-available/laravel.dev which may be missing - if not, we might need to find out if this file is being parsed, and if not, why not.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I didn't make that file, it was copied from the default and edited, I'm afraid I dont know enough about what I'm doing to "strip out any guff" so I only edited what seemed like it needed changing. I have updated my question with the results of ls -l. NOTE: Although I only have one site at the moment I want to get multiple sites on the same vm, until now I have been creating a separate vm for each site but it's surprising how quickly a terabyte can disappear that way. Presumably if I modify the document root in the apache config it will be a one site setup.

Comment: Also on the other guff point. It would be useful if I could separate out my error logs (and ideally mysql logs but I'll worry about that later) access logs could probably go but the closer I can emulate the type of system it will go live on the better. Also quite keen to learn how to do things properly (whichever way that may be) and start getting my head around lamp admin a bit better

Comment: From a speed and resource point of view, you are orders of magnitude better setting up virtual hosts then virtual machines for each site, and its actually not that hard to do with Apache.  Do you want to have a chat and we can try and solve your problem step by step ?  I'm arround for the next hour or so (but never used chat !!!)

Comment: Unfortunately I was a good 20 hours late checking back. But I would really appreciate your help if you have the time. I will be at my pc most of tomorrow and friday so hopefully our paths will cross at some point. If you could drop a comment here when your online and have a little time to spare I would be grateful - I'll keep an eye out for an alert. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Shall we meet to chat at 2:00am GMT (ie 2.5 hours from now) ?

Comment: Thanks again for you offer to help - I've got it working now. Unfortunately I dont really know how. I accidentally wiped my vb when clearing out some old ones, and when i set it all up again it worked. I no longer have *. at the beginning of the server name and have removed the trailing slash on the document root path as well as removing the first directory tags and their contents (not sure if any of this helped or if you care but just in case your interested in the outcome)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the tutorial I found here. Seems to give a run down on how to get setup using vhosts on Ubuntu. It also covers Arch Linux as well. But I was able to find out what my issue was after reading the tutorial, I was missing a simple step before following it. Possibly you are running into the same situation. 
http://www.adminempire.com/how-to-setup-v-host-on-apache/

Also possibly an Alias section would solve your issue with how to type in what you want and not have to include the localhost portion.

Comment: You seem to only be posting answers referencing one particular blog. If this is your site or you are a contributor then you must disclose any affiliation otherwise your posts will be marked as spam and deleted by the community